# Need to read a line of text from an archive.txt until "hhh" its found and then go to the next line

Tags: c++, c, fstream, getline

My teacher gave me this assignment, where I need to read words from a file and then do some stuff with them. My issue is that these words have to end with `"hhh"`, for example: `groundhhh`, `wallhhh`, etc.

While looking for a way to do this, I came up with the `getline` function from the `<fstream>` library. The thing is that `getline(a,b,c)` uses 3 arguments, where the third argument is to read until `c` is found but `c` has to be a `char`, so it doesn't work for me.

In essence, what I'm trying to achieve is reading a word from a file, `"egghhh"` for example, and make it so if `"hhh"` is read then it means the line finishes there and I receive `"egg"` as the word. My teacher used the term "sentinel" to describe this `hhh` thing.

This is my try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

ifstream read_archive;

void showListWords(){

    string word;

    string sentinel = "hhh";

    while (getline(read_archive,word,sentinel)){

        cout << word << endl;
    }
}

void openReadArchive(){

    read_archive.open("words.txt");

    if(read_archive.fail())

        cout << "There is something wrong with the archive" << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discovered, `std::getline()` allows you to specify only 1 `char` for the "sentinel" that it stops reading on, where `'\n'` (line break) is the default.

What you can do is use this default to read an entire line of text from the file into a `std::string`, then put that string into an `std::istringstream` and read words from that stream until the end of the stream is reached or you find a word that ends with `"hhh"`, eg:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>

void showListWords()
{
    string line, word;
    string sentinel = "hhh";

    while (getline(read_archive, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss >> word)
        {
            if (word.length() > sentinel.length())
            {
                string::size_type index = word.length() - sentinel.length();
                if (word.compare(index, sentinel.length(), sentinel) == 0)
                {
                    word.resize(index);
                    iss.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());
                }
            }

            cout << word << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

In which case, you could alternatively just read words from the original file stream, stopping when you find a word that ends with `"hhh"` and `ignore()` the rest of the current line before continuing to read words from the next line, eg:

```cpp
#include <limits>

void showListWords()
{
    string word;
    string sentinel = "hhh";

    while (read_archive >> word)
    {
        if (word.length() > sentinel.length())
        {
            string::size_type index = word.length() - sentinel.length();
            if (word.compare(index, sentinel.length(), sentinel) == 0)
            {
                word.resize(index);
                read_archive.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>:max, '\n');
            }
        }

        cout << word << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was really helpful!